# Determinant of block matrix with off diagonals as vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> I've been given an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ square matrix, which is written in the form of a block matrix with the following dimensions
>   $$ \begin{bmatrix}
>     (1\times1)       & (n\times1)\\
>     (n\times1)       & (n\times n) 
> \end{bmatrix} .$$
>   I need to compute the determinant.

I've tried to understand what is shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) on how to solve this but I'm still confused. Can someone offer any insight as to how I would go about solving this? Also, is there any decomposition, factorization, etc I can take advantage of with the off diagonals being $(n\times 1)$ and $(1\times n)$? I feel like there's some simplification I can utilize. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, looking at the formulas, I guess, the advantage in your special case is that you don't have to compute an inverse, since $A$ is just a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to evaluate determinants "by hand" is to use [Laplace's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix) to reduce its size by one and work iteratively until all determinants in the expression are 1x1 (i.e., numbers). This works best if you have lines or culumns in your matrix with many zeros.

The [formula you mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) about block matrices is another way to reduce the size of the determinant by one which can be used iteratively. I don't think there is any further possible simplification, you just have to go through the algebra.

Besides, this is not physics but maths. You may want to turn to [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) instead for future questions of this kind.